ArcGIS Online layer - delete/replace rows through python - file size ballooning
We had a consultant write a Python script for us a few months back. Part of the script takes a feature layer from an enterprise geodatabase and overwrites the data in an ArcGIS Online layer. Someone edits the EGDB data in Pro regularly, but very few rows are added, it is mostly just attribute edits. We started with 4400 rows when this went live and are up to 4416 at the moment. The script runs every 12 hours. The AGOL layer does not track changes, but does have sync enabled as the layer is used offline.
What I am seeing in AGOL since the script went live is that our storage use in AGOL is steadily climbing, and the size of the layer in AGOL is also climbing (started at 12MB and is now at 2GB!). Our credit usage per month has gone from a stable 450 to almost 1250 last month, with a jump of roughly 300 a month.
Below is the code that is running. I'm trying to troubleshoot this issue as our AGOL credits will run out soon if this continues.
Any ideas to remedy this?
    try:
        portal = AGOL_URL
        user = AGOL_USER
        password = AGOL_PASSWORD
        item_id = AGOL_ITEM_ID
        gis = arcgis.GIS(portal, user, password)
        item = gis.content.get(item_id)
        table_to_update = item.layers[0]
        new_features = gather_features(poetaxlots_fc)
        truncate(table_to_update, log_file_path)
        process_rows(new_features, table_to_update, log_file_path)
        email_message += "\n\nAGOL hosted feature layer overwritten successfully"
        send_email(email_message, start_time)
    except Exception as e:
        handle_error(e, start_time, log_file_path)
    finally:
        write_to_log_file(log_file_path, email_message)```



As I research this more I'm wondering if the archiving as part of Truncate is on. Can I use arcpy.management.DisableArchiving on an AGOL layer to fix this?

Any kind of archiving or versioning will cause this kind of behaviour.  I assume that is how the 'sync' functionality is done (ie, via archiving/versioniong).  You may be better off overwriting the hosted feature layer, rather than truncating and appending.  Although you may need to disable sync before it will let you overwrite.  (I've also just discovered a bug in truncating AGOL layers that may cause the layer's visibility to be reset to show at all zoom scales.)

Thanks @SonofaBeach for the suggestions. I turned off archiving of the SDE layer last Friday and unfortunately the AGOL layer is still growing.
If I overwrite the layer, would it still be properly linking in a web map? I feel like that would cause a new layer ID.

Archiving on the SDE layer is not going to make any difference to the AGOL layer size.  It is the ‘sync’ function on the AGOL layer that is using versioning (or similar) behind the scenes.  You would have to disable sync, then overwrite the layer, then re-enable sync.  (Of course this would cause problems for anyone who has data checked out - eg, in Field Maps - and then needs to check in their edits.). Overwriting a layer will not break the layer in a web map, if it is done correctly.

Just wanted to follow up with anyone who finds this from their own experiences. I've been working with ESRI directly on this problem for the past month and it has resulted in a bug they are tracking.
https://my.esri.com/#/support/bugs/bugs?bugNumber=BUG-000171566

I can't view the bug record.  Are you able to post a bit more information (I am curious).
